# Question about proof of Lucas Primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Lucas Primality Test. Suppose that $n > 1$ and $a$ are integers with $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$ and $a^{(n-1)/p} \not\equiv 1$ for all primes $p \mid n-1.$ Then $n$ is prime.

Proof. Suppose that the order of $a \in (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})^{\ast}$ is $k.$ Then  $a^{n-1} \equiv 1\mod n$ implies $k \mid n-1$ and $a^{(n-1)/p} \not\equiv 1$ implies that $k$ is not a proper divisor of $n-1 \Rightarrow k = n-1$ and $|(\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})^{\ast}| \geqslant n-1 \Rightarrow n$ prime. $\Box$

I understand the proof except for this step: "$a^{(n-1)/p} \not\equiv 1$ implies that $k$ is not a proper divisor of $n-1.$" Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that $k$ is a proper divisor of $n-1$. Then $kd=n-1$ for some $d\ge 2$. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $d$. Then $k$ divides $\frac{n-1}{p}$. Since $a$ has order $k$, we have that $a^{(n-1)/p}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, contradicting the fact that $a^{(n-1)/p}\not\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 5):

The proof is often stated in a way that obfuscates the essence of the matter. Since $\,a^{n-1}\equiv 1,\,$ the order $\,d\,$ of $\,a\,$ is a divisor of $\,n\!-\!1\,$ Therefore $\,d\neq n\!-\!1\,$ iff $\,d\,$ is a *proper* divisor of $\,n\!-\!1.\,$ By unique factorization, such proper divisors arise by deleting at least one prime $\,p\,$ from the factorization of $\,n.\,$ Therefore $\ d\mid n\!-\!1$ *properly* $\iff$ $d\mid (n\!-\!1)/p,\,$ for some prime $\,p\mid n$.

**Remark** $\ $ Compare to the set-theoretic analog $\ S\subsetneq P\!\iff\! S\subseteq P\backslash\{p\}\,$ for some $\,p\in P$